# Stereo camera structured light disparity problem

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, stereo-3d, gray-code

i want to build 3d scanner with stereo camera and LED Projector. I calibrated the stereo camera and created the mechanical system. I project gray code and capture them with two camera. I decoded the images and take correspondence image. But i can't triangulate the decoded points. This is my reference project for generate pattern and decode them.

[Reference Github project](https://github.com/elerac/structuredlight)

And this is my code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import structuredlight as sl


def generate_rectify_data(calib_data, size):
    XML_File = cv2.FileStorage(calib_data, cv2.FILE_STORAGE_READ)

    M1 = XML_File.getNode('Camera_Matrix_Left').mat()
    M2 = XML_File.getNode('Camera_Matrix_Right').mat()
    d1 = XML_File.getNode('Camera_Distortion_Left').mat()
    d2 = XML_File.getNode('Camera_Distortion_Right').mat()
    R = XML_File.getNode('Rotation_Matrix').mat()
    t = XML_File.getNode('Translation_Matrix').mat()

    flag = cv2.CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY
    
    R1, R2, P1, P2, Q = cv2.stereoRectify(cameraMatrix1=M1, cameraMatrix2=M2, 
    distCoeffs1=d1, distCoeffs2=d2, R=R, T=t, flags=flag, alpha=-1, imageSize=size, 
        newImageSize=size)[0:5]

    map_x_l, map_y_l = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(M1, d1, R1, P1, size, cv2.CV_32FC1)
    map_x_r, map_y_r = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(M2, d2, R2, P2, size, cv2.CV_32FC1)

    return map_x_l, map_y_l, map_x_r, map_y_r, P1, P2,Q


def rectify(img, map_x, map_y):
    res = cv2.remap(img, map_x, map_y, cv2.INTER_LINEAR, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
    return res


"""
***I generate pattern like this and capture them in another python script***

W = 240
H = 240

gray = sl.Gray()

imlist_posi_x_pat = gray.generate((W, H))
imlist_posi_y_pat = sl.transpose(gray.generate((H, W)))

"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    img_size = (1648, 1232)

    map_x_l, map_y_l, map_x_r, map_y_r, P1, P2, Q = generate_rectify_data(
    


    "C:/Users/XXX/PycharmProjects/Stereo_Structured_Light/Calibration_Data"
        "/Calibration_Parameters_1.xml", size=(1648, 1232))
    rect_list_l, rect_list_r = [], []

    imlist_posi_x_cap_R = []
    imlist_posi_y_cap_R = []
    imlist_posi_x_cap_L = []
    imlist_posi_y_cap_L = []

    for i in range(0,16):
        img_l = cv2.imread("C:/OxO_Scan/Images_1/Left_cam3/L_" + str(i) + ".png", 0)
        img_r = cv2.imread("C:/OxO_Scan/Images_1/Right_cam3/R_" + str(i) + ".png", 0)

        l_rect = rectify(img_l, map_x_l, map_y_l)
        r_rect = rectify(img_r, map_x_r, map_y_r)

        if i < 8:  # 8 for the horizontal, 8 for the vertical pattern images
            imlist_posi_x_cap_R.append(r_rect)
            imlist_posi_x_cap_L.append(l_rect)
        else:
            imlist_posi_y_cap_R.append(r_rect)
            imlist_posi_y_cap_L.append(l_rect)

    W = 240
    H = 240

    gray = sl.Gray()
    img_index_x_R = gray.decode(imlist_posi_x_cap_R, thresh=40)
    img_index_x_L = gray.decode(imlist_posi_x_cap_L, thresh=40)

    img_index_y_R = gray.decode(imlist_posi_y_cap_R, thresh=40)
    img_index_y_L = gray.decode(imlist_posi_y_cap_L, thresh=40)

    img_correspondence_x_r = cv2.merge([0.0 * np.zeros_like(img_index_x_R), 
               img_index_x_R / W, img_index_y_R / H])
    img_correspondence_r = np.clip(img_correspondence_x_r * 255.0, 0, 
               255).astype(np.uint8)

    img_correspondence_y_l = cv2.merge([0.0 * np.zeros_like(img_index_x_L), 
               img_index_x_L / W, img_index_y_L / H])
    img_correspondence_l = np.clip(img_correspondence_y_l * 255.0, 0, 
               255).astype(np.uint8)

    ####################################

    cv2.imshow("a", cv2.resize(img_correspondence_l, (640, 480)))
    cv2.imshow("b", cv2.resize(img_correspondence_r, (640, 480)))

    cv2.waitKey()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    img_correspondence_L_2 = np.copy(img_correspondence_l)
    img_correspondence_R_2 = np.copy(img_correspondence_r)

    cam_pts_l, cam_pts_r = [], []
    cam_pts_l2, cam_pts_r2 = [], []

    for i in range(img_correspondence_l.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img_correspondence_l.shape[1]):
            if (img_correspondence_l[i][j] != 0).any():
                qwert = img_index_x_L[i][j]

                cam_pts_l.append([j, i])
                cam_pts_r.append([j+qwert, i])

    cam_pts_l = np.array(cam_pts_l, dtype=np.float32)
    cam_pts_r = np.array(cam_pts_r, dtype=np.float32)

    cam_pts_l = np.array(cam_pts_l)[:, np.newaxis, :]
    cam_pts_r = np.array(cam_pts_r)[:, np.newaxis, :]

    pts4D = cv2.triangulatePoints(P1, P2, np.float32(cam_pts_l),np.float32(cam_pts_r)).T
    pts3D = (pts4D[:, :3] / pts4D[:, -1:])
```

I don't know what to do in code for loop "for i in range(img_correspondence_l.shape[0]):" For example, I cannot find where a point that I found using left correspondence image in the left camera image corresponds to in the right camera image. j+img_index_x_L[i][j] does not give correct results. What should i do here

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Do you have a literature reference to your structured light solution? I always thought that in structured light you have a projector and a single camera and compute disparity from the reference image to the camera image?

Comment: ^^ yea, why structured light AND stereo disparity ? please explain.

Comment: if you have a stereo pair of cameras, the only reason to project anything into the scene would be to get texture (for block matching) on textureless objects. -- that's a bunch of code... questions require a [mre] that has been debugged.

Comment: @Micka [This is my literature reference](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.6595v1.pdf). Also this is another [project](https://github.com/SILI1994/Structured-light-stereo) from stereo camera and disparity.

Comment: @berak Because stereo camera has a big advantage. It ensures that there is no need for a rigid installation of the projection device. It is possible to scan only with stereo camera calibration

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz As I said, I want to eliminate the need for a rigid installation of the projector. I'm also guessing that the calibration will be messed up when the projector focus is changed.